# Maximum nested function level reached

Tags: bash, zsh

I have directory hierarchy where the "root" directory has a file called "text.txt".  I want to find this "root" directory and then run the command 'foo' from within it.  Here is what I currently have

```
# Locates the root directory
locateRoot () {
  local root
  #Findup looks up through the directory hierarchy. I'm sure this works.
  root=$(findup text.txt  2>&/dev/null)  
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
    then
    echo "Root not found"
    return 1
  fi
  echo root
}

# Does foo from within the root directory
runFoo () {
  local myDir 
  myDir=$(locateRoot)
  pushd $myDir 1>&/dev/null
  foo $@
  popd 1>&/dev/null
}
```

However, whenever I run this program I get:

```
maximum nested function level reached
```

What's wrong with what I have? I'm positive that foo works as expected.

Comment: Your 'echo root' at line 11 should be 'echo $root'. Also, when writing a function that outputs some data that then you capture with $(), it's not a good idea to mix it with messages: you should write the error message at line 8 to stderr.

Comment: Care to briefly explain why? Sorry I'm really new to this.  Thanks :)

Comment: Because, in bash, to use the value of a variable "root", you need to write $root

Comment: Even after making the line 11 change it still doesn't work. Same error as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you `locateRoot` function you just `echo` only `root` not content of it, which is wrong and your script seems to very lengthy to perform some simple task.i give you sample script which print path to directory which contain `text.txt` file.

```
#! /bin/bash
locateRoot () 
{
    var=$(find / -iname "text.txt" -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)
    printf "%s \n" "$var"
}
```

you can see absolute path to that directory which contain that file. You can modify above script to perform certain task as you want by just `cd` to that directory like

```
cd $var
//execute your command in $var directory
```